# Update SQL query to update the primary key

Tags: sql

I have a table where the primary key is a combination of 2 columns, `ORG_ID` and `ORG_NAME`.

I want to run an update statement to update the `ORG_NAME` no matter what the `ORG_ID` is, i.e., for ORG_ID = anything

I tried the following which works if I give a particular ORG_ID

```
update org 
set org_name = 'abcd' 
where org_name = 'intl' and org_id = 100
```

But what I want is:

```
update org 
set org_name = 'abcd' 
where org_name = 'intl'
```

The above query will not work because it is a primary key violation. I need the above query to have a condition - and org_id = anything

Is there a way to do it?

Please note that this is the only way to do this as I cannot modify source code now.

Comment: can you provide data for this query: `select org_id, org_name where org_name = 'intl';` ?

Comment: Since I had changed the column names (as I was posting on this site) here is how the data would look like the following where the numeric is org_id and race is org_name:  1000 race
1001 race
1002 race
1003 race
1004 race
1006 race
1007 race

Comment: This is why you should NEVER use data that might change as part of your primary key. You almost certainly already have a row where org_name = 'intl' and org_id = 100

Comment: I want to set the org_name to something totally different that was never in the table. So I have to update the table with something like this: update org set org_name= 'abcd' where org_name='intl' and org_id could be anything

Comment: ok. So why don't you do that?

Comment: what should the sql be for org_id could be anything?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want to change org_name to 'intl' for the entire table regardless of what the org_id is? It is not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I wnat to change org_name to 'abcd' regardless of what the org_id is

Comment: You can't...that will violate the primary key. Unless you change your key structure this not an option. There is no way possible to have rows with a duplicate primary key.

Comment: You should add some sample data how it looks like before the update and how you want it to look like _after_ the update. Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: if this is one-time maintenance, change the table structure definition to remove the uniqueness requirement (i.e. delete the index), make the change, and then re-create the index/primary key structure.

Comment: can you please tell what kind of DBMS are you using? I tested it on SQL Server and the update was successful.  Check this out. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6ee2/1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two rows of data in your table:

```
Orgid=100, Orgname = 'qwerty', and Orgid=100, Orgname = 'azerty'
```

If you now try to update these two rows to have the same OrgName you will have a key violation. In my humble opinion, you probably need to rethink what you're doing and how you're storing your data.